# Apply Kirchhoff's law

Tags: code-golf, array, electrical-engineering

[Kirchhoff's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#) says that when you sum up all the currents (positive for the currents going to a junction, and negative for current leaving a junction), you will always get as result 0.

Look at the following diagram:

[image]

Using Kirchhoff's law, you can see that i1 + i4 - i2 - i3 = 0, so i1 + i4 = i2 + i3.

Given two lists, one with all the currents entering the junction and one with all the currents leaving the junction except one, output the last one.

Testcases:

```
[1, 2, 3], [1, 2] = 3
[4, 5, 6], [7, 8] = 0
[5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2], [8, 4, 5, 2, 1] = 6
```

The second list always has one item less than the first list. The output cannot be negative. Smallest program wins.

Comment: The puzzle would have been better if you actual gave resistor and current values. This Q seems like you have introduced the law just as a namesake. (The Q could have easily been stated without the law)

Comment: Kirchoff's _current_ law

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55806/whats-the-voltage-over-each-component).

Comment: Can you specify is we can just create a function that returns the result or actually print/return the result.

Answer (score 14):

## Jelly, 2 bytes

```
_S
```

[Try it here!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=X1M&input=&args=NSw3LDMsNCw1LDI+OCw0LDUsMiwx)

Takes the entering currents in the first argument, and the leaving currents in the second argument. `_` subtracts them pairwise, leaving the single element from the longer list as-is, and `S` sums the result.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 14 bytes

```
(.sum).(-).sum
```

Usage example: `( (.sum).(-).sum ) [5,7,3,4,5,2] [8,4,5,2,1]` -> `6`.

Sum each list and take the difference.

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
q~.-:+
```

Input uses two CJam-style arrays.

[Run all test cases.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%22%20%3D%20%22%2F0%3D%3AQ%3B%0A%0AQ~.-%3A%2B%0A%0A%5DoNo%7D%2F&input=%5B1%202%203%5D%20%5B1%202%5D%20%3D%203%0A%5B4%205%206%5D%20%5B7%208%5D%20%3D%200%0A%5B5%207%203%204%205%202%5D%20%5B8%204%205%202%201%5D%20%3D%206) (This reads multiple test cases at once and includes a framework to process each line individually, discarding the expected result from the input.)

#### Explanation

```
q~  e# Read and evaluate input.
.-  e# Elementwise difference.
:+  e# Get sum.
```

`.-` works reliably because we're guaranteed that the first list is always longer than the second. (Otherwise, the extraneous elements of the second list would be appended to the result which would add them to the sum instead of subtracting them.)

Comment: Congrats on exactly 80k!

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 3 <s>4.0</s> bytes

```
_hs
```

Inputs are: leaving currents first, then entering currents.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=X2hz&input=WzgsIDQsIDUsIDIsIDFdIApbNSwgNywgMywgNCwgNSwgMl0K)

```
_     % implicitly input array with leaving currents (except one). Negate
h     % implicitly input array with entering currents. Concatenate  
s     % sum of all elements in concatenated array
```

Comment: The exact same solution as mine, but with different letters haha, +1

Comment: @Adnan I saw! (+1 already)

Comment: @Adnan I've reduced to 3 bytes changing input order and concatenating both arrays. Maybe that can be applied to your answer as well?

Comment: Ahhh, I should really implement a concatenate function :p. Very nice answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Code:

```
OEO-
```

Explanation:

```
O     # Take the sum of the input list
 E    # Evaluate input
  O   # Take the sum of the input list
   -  # Substract from each other
```

---

Thanks to **Luis Mendo** for reminding me that I need to implement a concatenate function. If I've had implemented it sooner, it would have been 3 bytes:

**Non-competing version (3 bytes):**

The first list is the leaving current list, the second is the entering current list. Code:

```
(«O
```

Explanation:

```
(    # Negate the list, e.g. [3, 4, 5] would become [-3, -4, -5]
 «   # Concatenate the second list to the first
  O  # Take the sum and implicitly output it
```

Uses CP-1252 encoding.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 36 bytes

```
(a,b)=>eval(a.join`+`+'-'+b.join`-`)
```

```js
f=
(a,b)=>
    eval(
        a.join`+`
        +'-'+
        b.join`-`
    )

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' +
  'f([1,2,3],[1,2]) = ' + f([1,2,3],[1,2]) + '\n' +
  'f([4,5,6],[7,8]) = ' + f([4,5,6],[7,8]) + '\n' +
  'f([5,7,3,4,5,2],[8,4,5,2,1]) = ' + f([5,7,3,4,5,2],[8,4,5,2,1]) + '\n' +
'</pre>'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>17</s> 11 bytes

```
Tr@#-Tr@#2&
```

Quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

### Common Lisp, 40

```
(lambda(x y)(-(reduce'+ x)(reduce'+ y)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 11 bytes

```perl6
*.sum-*.sum
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &code = *.sum-*.sum;

say code [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]; # 3
say code [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]; # 0
say code [5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2], [8, 4, 5, 2, 1]; # 6
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 24 bytes

```
lambda a,b:sum(a)-sum(b)
```

or

## Python 2, 19 bytes

```
print sum(a)-sum(b)
```

depending if I am required to print the result or just create a function that returns it.

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 39 bytes

```
(i,o)=>i.reduceRight((r,a,j)=>r+a-o[j])
```

Because I wanted to use `reduceRight`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 30 bytes

```
a,b=map(sum,input());print a-b
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 6 bytes

```
-.*sRQ
```

Explanation

```
       - autoassign Q = eval(input())
   sRQ - map(sum, Q)
-.*    - imp_print(minus(*^))
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-.*sRQ&input=%5B%5B4%2C+5%2C+6%5D%2C+%5B7%2C+8%5D%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## K5, 5 bytes

```
-/+/'
```

Difference over (`-/`) sum over (`+/`) each (`'`).

In action:

```
  (-/+/')'((1 2 3;1 2);(4 5 6;7 8);(5 7 3 4 5 2;8 4 5 2 1))
3 0 6
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
-FsMQ
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-FsMQ&input=%5B4%2C+5%2C+6%5D%2C+%5B7%2C+8%5D&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-FsMQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+2%5D%0A%5B4%2C+5%2C+6%5D%2C+%5B7%2C+8%5D%0A%5B5%2C+7%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B8%2C+4%2C+5%2C+2%2C+1%5D&debug=0)

`M`ap `s`um on both input lists, then `F`old subtraction (`-`).

This could also be written as `-sQsE`, which takes the lists on two lines.

Answer (score 0):

## , 5 chars / 7 bytes

```
⨭î-⨭í
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B%5B4%2C%205%2C%206%5D%2C%20%5B7%2C%208%5D%5D&code=%E2%A8%AD%C3%AE-%E2%A8%AD%C3%AD)</kbd>

Wut.

## Explanation

`sum(input1) - sum(input2)`

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp REPL, SBCL <s>28</s> 24 bytes

write this into REPL:

```
#.`(-(+ #1=,@(read))#1#)
```

then write input lists like this:

```
(2 3 4)
(2 3)
```

I hope it's okay to use such list format (instead of e.g. `'(2 3 4)`)
I used [coredump's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71345/apply-kirchhoffs-law/71420#71420) as formula for my solution and then achieved his calculation effect in a different way.

#### Explanation

Let `e_1,...,e_n` be elements of the first list and `f_1,...,f_{n-1}` be elements of second list.
We want to evaluate expression `(-(+ e_1 e_2 ... e_n)f_1 f_2 ...f_{n-1})`
It would mean subtracting elements of second list from sum of elements of first list.
The needed expression is constructed like so:

backqoute stops evaluation

`#1=` saves a bit of writting, remembering `,@(read)`

`,@` stops effects of backquote (so that (read) will be evaluated) and takes elements out of a list.

`(read)` asks for input

`#1#` "loads" Lisp object saved by `#1=`

`#.` does evaluation of printed representation of an Lisp object